# Error Code: 403 Forbidden when submitting app to serverless application repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to publish my application to the serverless application repository but I get the error when I select my 'template.yml' file:

> Forbidden (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: 403
>   Forbidden; Request ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX; S3 Extended Request ID:
>   XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)

this is my 'template.yml':

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'

Resources:
  DataScraper:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: data_scraper.handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri:
        Bucket: ht-helpbot
        Key: data_scraper.zip
        Version: 1.0
      CodeUri: 's3://ht-helpbot/data_scraper.zip'
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
              TableName: HTServiceProviderTable
  FindService:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: find_service.handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      CodeUri: 's3://ht-helpbot/find_service.zip'
      Policies:
        - DynamoDBCrudPolicy:
              TableName: HTServiceProviderTable
```

Comment: Are you authenticated to the AWS account? It sounds like you do not have permission to publish the service on the account you are using.

Comment: Yes I am signed in to the account

Comment: Hmmmm. Then unless the account you are using has been restricted and not allowed to eprform that function, I have no idea. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to be able to publish an application using the Serverless Application Repository (serverlessrepo), serverlessrepo needs to be able to read the S3 artifacts uploaded to S3 during packaging of your application.

The standard way of providing these permissions, as described in [Publishing Applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverlessrepo/latest/devguide/serverless-app-publishing-applications.html#serverless-app-publishing-applications), is to provide `GetObject` to the `serverlessrepo` with a Resource Policy on your Bucket, such as the following example, where `<your-bucket-name>` would be replaced by the name of your S3 bucket.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service":  "serverlessrepo.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<your-bucket-name>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The reason that it started working when [you made your bucket public](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52683761/1017797) is because by doing so, you made the objects in that bucket, including the artifacts from packaging world readable, including the `serverlessrepo` service. While this works, as is noted in the [Access Control Lists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#finding-canonical-id) documentation:

> If you make your bucket public (not recommended) any unauthenticated user can upload objects to the bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating entering the following policy for my bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "serverlessrepo.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

where `BUCKET_NAME` is the name of my bucket.

Please take this answer with copious amounts of NaCl as I'm not really straight on AWS permissions.

Simply granting public READ access to my S3 bucket did not work for me (as it did for @harry). Also I had to include the packaged.yaml template built by `sam deploy` -- it includes the full S3 URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had to grant public read access to my S3 bucket and objects for it to work.

Comment: Not the recommended approach -- see @jamie Starke's explanation above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52685172/2317829